# Add phone number and note in Samsung Galaxy A72

Tags: calls, call-history, notes

My Samsung Galaxy A72 phone can add "notes" to phone numbers in my call log that do NOT have a contact associated with them.

I want to add a lot of numbers to my block list and add notes to them, is this possible somehow with adb or with some sort of program (that I can write myself, if I have to)?

Comment: I am not following, does the first statement contradict the second?  If not, then please make it clearer.

Comment: @RohitGupta, I am unsure how they contradict. First statement is "I can add notes to dialled phone numbers" and the second is "I want to programatically add dialled phone numbers."